# What does the 'ruby' mean in bundler output like so: "Could not find gem 'gem_name (= 1.1.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine."?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

So when gem info shows up, either in `gem list` output like so:

```
gem_name (1.1.0 ruby)
```

or in a bundler message like in the title:

> Could not find gem 'gem_name (= 1.1.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.

What does the `ruby` word after the version *mean*?

I've also seen `x86`, `x86-mingw32`.. This leads me to believe it indicates a platform-specific version of the gem.

But i've also seen `runtime`, so not sure how that would fit in with this theory, and `ruby` itself doesn't seem to specify a platform.

i am currently working on a Linux environment, and i built and installed a custom/private gem on it, and it shows up in `gem list --local` output:

```
gem_name (1.1.0)
```

but i still get the bundler output:

> Could not find gem 'gem_name (= 1.1.0) **ruby**' in the gems available on this machine.